# Why is not proxing?

Tags: nginx, fetch

There is a request to a third-party API, let it be https://ws75.aptoid.com/api/7/apps/search?query=asd
There is a nginx.conf config with rows:

```
location /api/7/apps/search {
   proxy_pass https://ws75.aptoide.com/;
}
```

(of course, Location lies inside the Server, which lies inside HTTP)
There is a React application with a form, when sending which the following query occurs:

```
fetch('/api/7/apps/search?' + new URLSearchParams({
                query: input.value
            }))
```

Why does not send a request to https://ws75.aptoid.com/api/7/apps/search?query=asd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, do simply from the root url location :

```
location / {
   proxy_pass https://ws75.aptoide.com/;
}
```

?
URI will be add to proxy_pass automatically.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer.
Unfortunately, there are requests to other domains, I would not like to proxy them all through https://ws75.aptoide.com, because it can entail additional errors.

Comment: Ok sorry, i don't understand in proxy_pass, witch part of url need to change.